# How to handle "Am I right?" homework questions

Tags: discussion, homework

The procedure to deal with homework questions with no effort is pretty well established around here: vote to close.

However, what about questions where the problem is laid out and then answered completely by the questioner? One such example is this about [aromaticity](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63670/why-is-this-compound-not-antiaromatic). I don't think there's anything to add. I'm almost inclined to vote to close for "unclear what you're asking", but that doesn't seem right either.

Any thoughts from the community?

Comment: This was raised earlier (duplicate). I do share your concern and am slightly frustrated at the lack of resolution on the duplicate question. Personally I want to [rework the homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3457/16683) to subsume such cases. That said, meta.chem is a slow-moving place, it takes a long time to come to consensus and especially with such a major issue, I think it will be a while before we reach a conclusion. Thanks for posting this though.

Comment: @orthocresol Sorry for the dupe. Foolishly I searched for "am i right" instead of "AMIRITE". Kids these days.